# Angular Typescript: How to use string in array like name of object?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two objects like this:

```
a: {companies: {id: 1, name: 'companya1'}}
b: {companies: {id: 1, name: 'companyb1'}}
```

I would use an array like this:

```
names: ['a', 'b']
```

and in a template html i would do this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let name of names">
  <div *ngFor="let company of name.companies | keyvalue">
    <p>{{company | json}}</p>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Is there a way to reach this goal?

Comment: *I have two objects* So are they two different objects or two objects inside one object?

Comment: they are two different objects

Answer (score 0):

You could use a string indexer like this:

```js
public nameCompanies = {
  a: { ... },
  b: { ... }
};

public names = ['a', 'b'];
```

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let name of names">
  <div *ngFor="let company of nameCompanies[name].companies">
    <p>{{company | json}}</p>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```